# How to use jquery autocomplete with var?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, closures

I have a function that use jQuery autocomplete inside it:

```
var row_num = 5;
function addModule() {
    // function addModule code
    $('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            //function code
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            //function code
            $('input[name=\'module[' + row_num + '][featured]\']').attr('value',
            data.join());
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    // function addModule code continues
});​
```

Var row_num doesn't work in body of autocomplete. I tried to declare it additionally in "select" and other different places but nothing. Looking through ui autocomplete documentation bring no results.
How to get autocomplete use my var ?

Comment: It works. http://jsfiddle.net/qN2bL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
            $('input[name=\'module[' + row_num + '][featured]\']').attr('value', data.join());
```

To this

```
            var t = 'input[name=\'module[' + row_num + '][featured]\']'
            alert("This is the value: "+t.toString());
            $(t).attr('value', data.join());
```

Maybe you are not expecting what you see?

---

This should be part of the closure.  Have you tried it this way?

```
function addModule() {
    var row_num = 5;
    // function addModule code
    $('input[name=\'product\']').autocomplete({
        delay: 0,
        source: function(request, response) {
            //function code
        },
        select: function(event, ui) {
            //function code
            $('input[name=\'module[' + row_num + '][featured]\']').attr('value',
            data.join());
        },
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    // function addModule code continues
});​
```

Comment: @Sergey - Then the problem is not with the closure, see commment above.

Comment: Thx. Now I see another the problem)